# Not loading React files when serving with Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I've already built my app created with create react app. And everything works fine when I use
`app.use(express.static('public'));`. I write http://localhost:3005/ and all my components load.

However, when I use `app.use('/static', express.static('public'))` and write http://localhost:3005/static, it seems that only index.html loads, without the rest of the files. So my components do not load.

[This is what I got in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z0hu.png)

As you can see, the status is 404:

```
GET /static/css/main.d58caaff.chunk.css 404 2.749 ms - 173
GET /static/js/2.eef0f33d.chunk.js 404 0.996 ms - 168
GET /static/js/main.a8e1190f.chunk.js 404 0.425 ms - 171
GET /static/js/2.eef0f33d.chunk.js 404 0.224 ms - 168
GET /static/js/main.a8e1190f.chunk.js 404 0.230 ms - 171
GET /manifest.json 404 0.371 ms - 152
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is [How to Deploy a React App to a Subdirectory](https://scottvinkle.me/blogs/work/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory).

I followed steps 3 and 4. However, my components loaded in the route `http://localhost:3005/adminView/adminView`.

In my case, step 3 and 4 were not necessary. I left it like this:

```
return (
    <Router basename={'/adminView'}>
      <Header />
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`/`} component={OnlineOrders} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

Then I finally use   `app.use('/adminView', express.static('admin'));` in my server.

Answer (score 0):

try set the static path with [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) module

example:

```js
import { join } from 'path'

app.use('/static', express.static(join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

you can also check [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: I've tried  app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/..', 'public'))). But I'm getting the same error. (status 404)